# Turtles: Fresh water in aquarium turned red after few minutes

Tags: health, aquarium, turtles, containment

Around 30-40 mins ago I changed aquarium water, cleaned the filter and dropped some toya food for my turtles. Now I am seeing water turned red, I have already checked there are no cuts, bites or bruises on turtles.

What could be the reason, why water is red? Is this infection? Could it effect me also because I changed water with my hands, w/o any gloves, using buckets.

Infos:

1. The source of the new water is city Supply = tap water = hard water. Its the same source of supply from past 9 years for them. Touchwood! There growth is pretty good.
2. I change the water whenever I see that the water is too cloudy due to food, I change the water, approx in every 20-30 days.
3. I have been feeding same food for a pretty long time. It always seemed that they like it because the moment I drop the food they grab it like they are hungry from ages. [image]
4. I do not use anything for dechlorination. Looks like I don't need dechlorination. They are going w/o it.
5. I Did not use one or employ other techniques such as ageing my water.

Comment: is it possible for you to post a picture of the water,fill a glass whith water and hold it aginst a white background.

Comment: @trondhansen I changed the immediately after I saw it

Comment: How deep can you look inside the water? 10cm? To the backside of the aquarium?

Comment: How deep can I look? I am not looking into the water from top, like removing the aquarium lid and then look inside. I am looking into throght the glass from a distance of 3-4 feet and it looks red-ish (dull red).

Comment: Wow the same thing happen with my turtle water yesterday. I freaked out because i didn't know why the water turned bloody red. I took a picture of it which im trying to post